# Need view to calculate difference even if there is no child record

Tags: mysql

The following view is supposed to calc the *difference* between Total & Amount. But if there is no corresponding payment entered in bill_pay_allocations, the view fails to calculate. How can I get a calc a difference even if there is no corresponding payment?

```
SELECT
`alphabase`.`bill_ing_sheets`.`INVOICE_NO` AS `INVOICE_NO`,
`alphabase`.`bill_ing_sheets`.`TOTAL` AS `TOTAL`,
`alphabase`.`bill_pay_allocations`.`AMOUNT` AS `AMOUNT`,
`alphabase`.`bill_pay_allocations`.`AMOUNT` - `alphabase`.`bill_ing_sheets`.`TOTAL` AS `Difference` 
FROM
`alphabase`.`bill_ing_sheets` left join `alphabase`.`bill_pay_allocations` 
ON
`alphabase`.`bill_pay_allocations`.`BILLING_ID` = `alphabase`.`bill_ing_sheets`.`BILLING_ID` 
left join `alphabase`.`bill_payments` 
ON
`alphabase`.`bill_payments`.`PAYMENT_ID` = `alphabase`.`bill_pay_allocations`.`PAYMENT_ID`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a LEFT OUTER JOIN between bill_ing_sheets and bill_pay_allocations. Use a Case statement to look for Null values in Amount and replace that with 0.

Also propagate the LEFT OUTER JOIN if it is necessary on the bill_payments.

Please see the code below.

```
SELECT
`alphabase`.`bill_ing_sheets`.`INVOICE_NO` AS `INVOICE_NO`,
`alphabase`.`bill_ing_sheets`.`TOTAL` AS `TOTAL`,
(case when `alphabase`.`bill_pay_allocations`.`AMOUNT` is not null then `alphabase`.`bill_pay_allocations`.`AMOUNT` else 0 end) AS `AMOUNT`,
(case when `alphabase`.`bill_pay_allocations`.`AMOUNT` is not null then `alphabase`.`bill_pay_allocations`.`AMOUNT` else 0 end) - `alphabase`.`bill_ing_sheets`.`TOTAL` AS `Difference` 
FROM
`alphabase`.`bill_ing_sheets` left outer join `alphabase`.`bill_pay_allocations` 
ON
`alphabase`.`bill_pay_allocations`.`BILLING_ID` = `alphabase`.`bill_ing_sheets`.`BILLING_ID` 
left outer join `alphabase`.`bill_payments` 
ON
`alphabase`.`bill_payments`.`PAYMENT_ID` = `alphabase`.`bill_pay_allocations`.`PAYMENT_ID`
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I wouldn't have seen the forest for the trees. One comment though, in MySQL, at least, left join & left outer join are one and the same.